# GridView Header Checkbox Change is not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview, internet-explorer-9

In An ASP.NET 2.0 Web Application, there is a grid view in which rows are created dynamically with 1st column as a checkbox. The user either checks individual checkbox in GridView Rows or checks only Check All to check all rows in GridView.

I added a Template Field with Header Template(Header Row) and Item Template(Data Rows).
I had add javascript methods on to check all data rows checkboxes when user click on header row checkbox in GridView_RowDataBound event.

The Javascript function get the GridView by "getElementById('GridViewName') and checks whether row's first cell type is checkbox then checked that checkbox.

```
    //get gridview from the document
    var grid = document.getElementById(gridId);
    //total rows in the gridview
    var rowsCount = grid.rows.length;
    //cond: sent by header checkbox 
    if (bIsHeader == true) {
        //loop starts from 1. rows[0] points to the header.
        for (i = 1; i < rowsCount; i++) {
            //get the reference of first column
            cell = grid.rows[i].cells[0];
            //cond: confirm type of the cell child
            if (cell.childNodes[0].type == "checkbox") {
                //assign header checkbox state to every row
                cell.childNodes[0].checked = chkBox;
            }
        }
    }
```

It was working fine in IE 8 and lower version. But, in IE 9, when this javascript function comes to get childNodes of row to check whether it is checkbox or not. It does not step in.

What I wanted to fix ?

In my code, **row.childNodes** does not working in IE 9. What is the alternative of this property in IE 9 and above ?

Comment: Are you sure that issue is about **row.childNodes**? I prepared JsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ENZhp/) and this example working in IE9 and it does using **row.childNodes** property

Comment: Yeah, but I figured it out now. I replaced row.childNodes with row.children and it is working on IE9 and IE 8 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**row.children** property works for me to accomplish this task.